# Can't load node from .jdf file in Vbscript

Tags: object, xpath, vbscript, nodes, jdf

I'm trying to get a value from a node in a .jdf file.
It gives us an error

`object required: 'curNode'`

in line no. 13 - `inputFolder = curNode.getAttribute("Amount")`

We don't really know what to do... any help please?

Thank you

```
'creates the msxml object
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
Dim xmlDataPath,retVal
xmlDataPath = "C:\Users\liatte\Desktop\Aviv Omer Neta\JDFs to Txt\a.jdf"

'load the xml data of the script
retVal=xmlDoc.load(xmlDataPath)

'get input folder
Set curNode = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//JDF/ResourceLinkPool/ComponentLink")
Dim inputFolder
inputFolder = curNode.getAttribute("Amount")
```

Comment: Show us a sample of the XML input document. It probably has a default namespace declaration (e.g. `xmlns="http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1"`) which requires you to change your XPath expressions by defining a prefix for the namespace (e.g. `xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:jdf='http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1'"` and using it (`Set curNode = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//jdf:JDF/jdf:ResourceLinkPool/jdf:ComponentLink")`).

Comment: You are amazing!! That was the exact problem, even same link. We found out about it and came to search online, then we saw your answer. Can you please explain what you did here? And what is "default namespace declaration"? Thank you!

Comment: I posted an answer with some explanations and some links to explain XML and namespaces and how to script them with MSXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an XPath expression like `//JDF/ResourceLinkPool/ComponentLink` does not select elements in your input document then it is likely that you are processing a document which uses namespaces, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespaces.

With XPath 1.0 a path like `/foo/bar` selects `bar` child elements of `foo` elements in no namespace while with an XML document of the form

```
<foo xmlns="http://example.com/ns1">
  <bar>baz</bar>
</foo>
```

the elements are in the namespace `http://example.com/ns1`.

With your sample there is probably a default namespace declaration (e.g. `xmlns="http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1"`) which requires you to change your XPath expressions by defining a prefix for the namespace e.g.

```
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:jdf='http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1'"
```

and using it:

```
Set curNode = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//jdf:JDF/jdf:ResourceLinkPool/jdf:ComponentLink")
```

Documentation for MSXML is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms756048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with the error, check

```
If curNode Is Nothing Then
   ... 
Else
   Dim inputFolder
   ...
End If
```

Obviously your assumptions (XPath expression) about the source file are wrong, when selectSingleNode() fails.